# Facing error in case matching in scala

Tags: regex, scala, pattern-matching

I have stored the reg-ex and name pair in map.
And reading a line from a file if any of reg-ex matches to the  line than corresponding name from the map should be printed.
My sample source code is

```
for (line <- Source.fromFile(dirName).getLines) {
  for ((name, regex) <- map) {
    line match {
      case regex => println("In regex " + regex, name)
      //case _ => //After adding this line it says that this part of code is not reachable
    }
  }
}
```

After printing the result I am facing strange behavior: case got triggered for those reg-ex also for which line does not match, and in the printing result reg-ex is automatically converted to string like
if reg-ex is `^stack\s+overflow`, then in print result it printing like stack overflow.

Correct me if I am missing something or suggest me if there is any good alternative to do that.

Comment: Have you already checked the docs: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex ?

Comment: can you also show how your map looks like?

Comment: Your case match simply binds `line` to a new local variable called `regex` (which shadows the outer variable of the same name). It doesn't do any regex matching.